# how to reset the form in adaptive card

Tags: adaptive-cards

I am new to the adaptive cards and till now I have not tried with resetting the form now I got the requirement to reset the form. I don't have any idea how to clear the selected values in adaptive cards. Could any one please help me

Comment: Hey,could you specify this a bit more? If i took you right you want to have a button that clears all input fields?

Comment: yes i want a button clear, if i click on that clear button all the selected values of the fields should be reset to initial values

Comment: Adaptivecards as such on its own can't do that. But there are options depending on where you are using the card. In MS Teams you can add an action button that "Updates" the card behind the scenes and just sends the empty card again. So, where are you using the card?

Comment: I am using this card in web application which uses react  and I am using JavaScript adaptive card

Comment: Well in that case i would just add a button myself via js that would just re-render the card. Cards itself dont have any reset functionality. You would have tobdo that yourself.